# Url Hiding in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can any one please help me out.
How to manage the url in the address bar,which will not to be changed for every operation in certain controller(create/Edit/Delete like ).

for Example if we are in page like 'http://localhost/Music'

when we are adding we will get 'http://localhost/Music/Add'

but when editing the particular item details 'http://localhost/Music/Edit?id=XXXXXXX'

here, I want to display the url Every time as "http://localhost/Music/ " only,How ?

Comment: I know of a few workarounds for this issue, but none of them are really recommendable because they impact the flow of your application.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use AJAX if you want the user to stay on the same page all the time. So basically you will not be performing full postbacks but only asynchronous AJAX calls.

You could use the `Ajax.*` helpers or implement this functionality yourself using for example [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: In my case i have three controller which are returning three different view.

Comment: With AJAX you could have your controller actions return PartialViews, instead of full Views. You will also need to have a placeholder somewhere on your page (for example a `<div>` element with a given `id`) that will be used to receive the result of the execution of this controller action.